# complex limits, how to show they go to 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In complex integration my book uses that some limits go to zero as R goes to infinity. However I do not now how to show this, these two limits are:

$e^{-\pi(R^2+2iRy-y^2)}$, where y is a real number that can vary from 0 to a real numer b.

The second limit is $e^{-R^2e^{2it}}R$. Normally I would have used l'hopitals rule, but when I have complex number, it isn't clear how to do this, t is a number from 0 to $\pi/4$.

For the firs limit I can try something like this:

$|e^{-\pi(R^2+2iRy-y^2)}|\le K|e^{-\pi(R^2+2iRy)}|=K|e^{-\pi R(R+2iy)}|$, where K is a real number but how do I show that this goes to 0?, the problem is that I have a complex number in the exponent.

For the second one I get what I need if I can show that $|e^{-R^2e^{2it}}|\le L|e^{-R^2}|$, because then I can work with real numbers, but how do I do this?

Comment: Don't forget that you are going to integrate these quantities. You should prove that the integrals go to zero.

Comment: Generally, what is $\lvert e^z\rvert$? If you recall that, the first estimate is immediate, and you see that for the second, you need a tighter restriction on $t$.

Comment: @DanielFischer For the first one you mean that $|e^{z}|=e^{Re(z)}$?, i think that gives me the answer yes. I am sorry, I meant that t is a number from 0 to $\pi/4$. Can I then show that the second one goes to 0?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. As for the second, that doesn't tend to $0$ for $t = \frac{\pi}{4}$, only for $0 \leqslant t < \frac{\pi}{4}$. But, probably you don't want to show the pointwise convergence of the function to $0$ as $R\to\infty$, but that the integral over a circular arc of radius $R$ tends to $0$, and that follows.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah I actually need that $\int_0^{\pi /4}e^{-R^2*e^{2it}}*R*e^{it}*idt=0$, so I thought showing that it goes to 0 was what I had to do, but I see now that the absolute value for the function is not bounded on the interval I integrate over. So how does the result then follow? If I only had to integrate to $\pi/4 -\epsilon$, I see that the integral would be zero, because there the function converges uniformly to 0, but how do I extend it the last part of the arc?, what controls that the integral does not because a non-ero number in the limit?

Comment: It does not equal $0$, it tends to $0$ for $R\to\infty$. One way to prove that uses the inequality $\sin t \geqslant \frac{2}{\pi} t$ for $0 \leqslant t \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$. Can you find a proof with that hint?

Comment: @DanielFischer No I reduced the problem to having to show that $\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2*cos(2*t)}*R=0$, so the inequality for sin do not help me that much.